# Bonsai from tree cuttings

Tags: trees, propagation, bonsai, cuttings

Is there a way to make a bonsai from a normal tree cutting (not from a bonsai cutting)? I was just thinking for instance of making a bonsai maple from a normal size field maple, or ash, etc. What trees are suitable for this? (I am in UK)

Comment: Oops, I interpreted your question as  (not a bonsai cutting ),  did you want to start from seed or a cutting?

Comment: @kevinsky I meant from a tree cutting :) not from a bonsai cutting

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  There is no such thing as a bonsai cutting.  A bonsai is just a normal tree, nothing more.  There are various ways to reduce leaf size.  And of course some trees are better suited to bonsai than others.  ie ones with smaller natural leaves if it is desired to show with leaves.  If not then leaf size doesn't matter if you want to show it in it's naked winter state.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, look around your area for trees with small leaves.  Those are easiest to pick out as being suitable. This question is very localized to your area.
Examples from my area include:

- Amur maple  -smaller maple with small leaves, vigorous seedlings
- burr oak  (quercus macrocarpa) - not a fast grower
- hemlock seedlings from the forest floor

Comment: Hemlocks and Burr oak are both challenging to grow from cuttings.